# How to do a regression starting from a list of list of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to run a regression in python. I have a list of lists (part of a bigger list) that looks something like this:

```
[[1307622004, 0.0, 339.093, 130.132], 
[10562004, 0.0, 206.818, 62.111], 
[127882004, 0.0, 994.624, 360.497], 
[63702004, 0.0, 89.653, 19.103], 
[655902004, 0.0, 199.613, 83.296], 
[76482004, 0.0, 1891.0, 508.0], 
[16332004, 0.0, 160.344, 25.446], 
[294352004, 0.0, 67.115, 22.646], 
[615922004, 0.0, 134.501, 41.01], 
[1212572004, 0.0, 232.616, 5.086], 
[658992004, 0.0, 189.155, 7.906], 
[61962004, 0.0, 806.7, 164.1], 
[121712004, 0.0, 1147.532, 271.014], 
[1250142004, 0.0, 29.556, -5.721], 
[148082004, 0.0, 22.05, -17.655]]
```

It looks like this because each line is a row from a CSV file I am importing the data from. From this point on, please look at the elements in the list as columns of variables to better understand what I am trying to a regression on. For example, the first 4 lists from the list would look something like that turned into columns (I do not need the variables turned into columns I've done it for illustration purposes):

```
1307622004     0.0    339.093    130.132
10562004       0.0    206.818    62.111
127882004      0.0    994.624    360.497
```

To continue my example, I want the first column to be my dependent variable and all the other columns to be independent variables.
I have tried using numpy to transform the list into an array and then apply sklearn regression. Below is a code snippet:

**Important to note:** The list_of_lists contains many elements similar to the list I have provided at the beginning of the question.

```
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

for item in list_of_lists:
    test_array = np.asarray(item)
    # print(test_array)
    X, Y = test_array[:, 0], test_array[:, 1]
    mdl = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
    scores = LinearRegression.score(X, Y)
    print('--------------------------')
```

The problem is that I get the following output:

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

I am quite new to python and the usage of arrays, matrixes in python so I don't really understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you're iterating through your list of lists. Better is just to fit your regression to your array. Also, if you want the first column to be your response (dependent) variable, and all the rest to be predictor (independent) variables, you need to change the definitions of `X` and `Y`, because as you have it, you have the first column as a predictor and the second column as a response:

```
test_array = np.asarray(list_of_lists)
# Set independent variables to be all columns after first, dependent to first col
X, Y = test_array[:, 1:], test_array[:, 0]

# Create a regressor 
reg = LinearRegression()
# Fit it to your data   
mdl = reg.fit(X, Y)
# Exctract the R^2
scores = reg.score(X,Y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I get what is happening and how I can move around things. Awesome!

Comment: Glad I could help :)